# LC50 change in units and confidence limits

Tags: confidence-interval, dose-response

I performed a dose-response experiment and I have estimated the LC50 and a confidence interval. I've been asked to provide results expressed in several units (mg/kg and mg/L).

I assume that I can transform my LC50, but I'm not sure about what happens with my confidence limits, as variance is implied in their calculation. However, [variance seems not being relevant in this case](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162241/back-transforming-confidence-intervals). Sorry if this is a too basic question, but can I simply transform them as I do with my LC50?

That is, if (a) I transform my confidence limits from mg/kg to mg/L and (b) I fit a new regression on the mg/L values, will I obtain the same LC50 and the same confidence limits? Why?

Edit: I estimated the LC50 by a probit regression. CI calculations are based on Fieller's theorem.

Comment: It might depend on the model, but that's unlikely: most statistical procedures of such data do not change when you change the unit of measurement.  But sometimes people do weird things in their models, so it would help to tell us specifically how you estimate the LC50 and compute its CI.

Comment: Thank you, @whuber. I edited my question to include the model used for LC50 and method for CI calculations.